# Pandas: Merging two columns into one with corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with a bunch of names which appear in two columns
It is in the following layout

```
Winner    Value_W     Loser     Value_L

Jack         5         Sally       -3
Sally        2         Max         -1
Max          4         Jack        -2
Lucy         1         Jack        -6
Jack         6         Henry       -3
Henry        5         Lucy        -4
```

I then filtered on columns 'Winner' and 'Loser' to get all rows which Jack appears in using the following code

```
pd.loc[(df['Winner'] == 'Jack') | (df['Loser'] == 'Jack')]
```

Which returns the following:

```
Winner    Value_W    Loser    Value_L

Jack         5       Sally      -3
Max          4       Jack       -2
Lucy         1       Jack       -6
Jack         6       Henry      -3
```

I am now looking to generate one column which only has Jack and his corresponding values.
So in this example, the output I want is:

```
New_1    New_2

Jack     5
Jack    -2
Jack    -6
Jack     6
```

I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You could `wide_to_long` after renaming the columns slightly. This allows you to capture additional information, like whether that row is a Win or Loss. Or if you don't care do `df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)`

```
d = {'Winner': 'Person_W', 'Loser': 'Person_L'}
df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns=d).reset_index(),
                      stubnames=['Person', 'Value'],
                      i='index',
                      j='Win_Lose',
                      sep='_',
                      suffix='.*')

df1[df1.Person == 'Jack']
#               Person  Value
#index Win_Lose              
#0     W          Jack      5
#4     W          Jack      6
#2     L          Jack     -2
#3     L          Jack     -6
```

---

If that specific ordering is important, we still have the original Index so:

```
df1.sort_index(level=0).query('Person == "Jack"').reset_index(drop=True) 
#  Person  Value
#0   Jack      5
#1   Jack     -2
#2   Jack     -6
#3   Jack      6
```

Answer (score 3):

You should go `wide_to_long` for sure, but here is a hidden function so called `lreshape` (May remove in the future, depends on pandas' developer)

```
pd.lreshape(df,{'name':['Winner','Loser'],'v':['Value_W','Value_L']}).query("name=='Jack'")
Out[75]: 
   name  v
0  Jack  5
4  Jack  6
8  Jack -2
9  Jack -6
```

Comment: Ah this is the second time I've seen this hidden function. Need to commit it to memory :D

Comment: I don't think of this nor `wide_to_long` as much as I should.

Comment: @piRSquared np.where should be the fastest :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
name = 'Jack'
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'New_1': name, 
    'New_2': df.loc[df['Winner'].eq(name), 'Value_W'].tolist() 
             + df.loc[df['Loser'].eq(name), 'Value_L'].tolist()})
  New_1  New_2
0  Jack      5
1  Jack      6
2  Jack     -2
3  Jack     -6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `numpy.where` after you've selected only the rows with 'Jack'

```py
import numpy as np
df['New_2'] = np.where(df['Winner'] == 'Jack', df['Value_W'], df['Value_L'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly:

1. Split it into two dataframes
2. Rename some columns
3. Join
4. Possibly drop extra rows

```
df_win = df[['Winner', 'Value_W']].rename(columns={'Winner':'Name','Value_W':'Value'})
df_lose = df[['Loser', 'Value_L']].rename(columns={'Loser':'Name','Value_W':'Value'})

df = df_win.join(df_lose, on='Name', how='outer')
df.loc[df.Name == 'Jack']
```

I do really like ALollz's answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Also [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) + [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) **with `axis=1`**

```
new_df=df.where(df.eq('Jack').shift(axis=1)).sum(axis=1,min_count=1).dropna().to_frame('value')
new_df.insert(0,'Name','Jack')
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   Name  value
0  Jack    5.0
2  Jack   -2.0
3  Jack   -6.0
4  Jack    6.0
```